Где в Java-проекте разместить ТЗ (техническое задание)?
В какой директории и файле принято размещать ТЗ?
Делаю тестовое задание на Java с помощью Spring'а. По заданию необходимо оформить ТЗ в произвольной форме и разместить вместе с проектом на github.
Нужно ли размещать произвольное ТЗ внутри README.md или следует создавать отдельный файл? Если последнее, то как назвать, чтобы его нашли?

т.к. в произвольной форме, то можно где угодно:

можно не париться и разместить в README.md,
можно в отдельном md файле, можно со ссылкой из README, а можно и без, не найти в гитхабе файл надо постараться ;)
можно в javadoc описаниях классов распределить если так удобнее.

просто представьте себе что Вы проверяете это задание и естественно не знаете деталей ТЗ, где бы и в какой форме Вам было бы удобнее при этом его читать?
